# algorithm challenge. generating new structure structure from tree like structure

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list, tree

below is my current code and is runnable. however this `console.log(JSON.stringify(results2) == JSON.stringify(payloadTasks))` fails. i need to make this pass

```
const payloadTasks = [
    {
        name: "a",
        parallel: {
            tasks: [
                {name: "a1", parallel: {tasks: [{name: "a1a"}]}},
                {name: "a2"}
            ]
        }
    },
    {name: "b"},
    {
        name: "c",
        parallel: {
            tasks: [{name: "c1"}]
        }
    }
]
 
const edges = [
    {source: "a", target: "a1"},
    {source: "a", target: "a2"},
    {source: "a1", target: "a1a"},
    {source: "a1a", target: "b"},
    {source: "a2", target: "b"},
    {source: "b", target: "c"},
    {source: "c", target: "c1"}
]
 
const nodes = [
    {name: "a", data: {type: "parallelNode", isRoot: true}},
    {name: "b", data: {isRoot: true}},
    {name: "c", data: {type: "parallelNode", isRoot: true}},
    {name: "a1", data: {type: "parallelNode"}},
    {name: "a1a", type: ""},
    {name: "a2"},
    {name: "c1"}
]
const nodesWithoutIsRoot = [
    {name: "a", data: {type: "parallelNode"}},
    {name: "b", data: {}},
    {name: "c", data: {type: "parallelNode"}},
    {name: "a1", data: {type: "parallelNode"}},
    {name: "a1a", type: ""},
    {name: "a2"},
    {name: "c1"}
]
 
 
function convertToPayloadTasks(nodes, edges) {
    const taskMap = nodes.reduce((acc, node) => {
        acc[node.name] = {
            name: node.name,
            ...(node.data?.type === 'parallelNode' && {parallel: {tasks: []}}),
        };
        return acc;
    }, {});
 
    edges.forEach(edge => {
        const parentTask = taskMap[edge.source];
        const childTask = taskMap[edge.target];
 
        if (parentTask.parallel) {
            parentTask.parallel.tasks.push(childTask);
        } else {
            console.error(`Attempting to add child to non-parallel parent: ${parentTask.name}`);
        }
    });
 
    // Extract root tasks based on the isRoot flag
    const rootTasks = nodes.filter(node => node.data?.isRoot).map(node => taskMap[node.name]);
 
    // Optionally, if a non-root task is not a child in any edge, it could also be considered a root task
    // This depends on your specific requirements and how you define a root task in the absence of an isRoot flag
    const additionalRootTasks = Object.values(taskMap).filter(task =>
        !rootTasks.includes(task) && !edges.some(edge => edge.target === task.name)
    );
 
    return [...rootTasks, ...additionalRootTasks];
}
 
 
const results = convertToPayloadTasks(nodes, edges);
const results2 = convertToPayloadTasks(nodesWithoutIsRoot, edges);
console.log(JSON.stringify(results) == JSON.stringify(payloadTasks))
console.log(JSON.stringify(results2) == JSON.stringify(payloadTasks))
```

i need to make this pass true. but i'm unable to do so. it currently works with the field `isRoot` but once i remove it, then it does not work.
i would like to figure out if it's possible to generate the same structure as payloadTasks but removing the field `isRoot`

appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a helper object for all references to each other.

BTW, your data contains some edges

```
{ source: "a1a", target: "b" },
{ source: "a2", target: "b" },
{ source: "b", target: "c" }
```

which do no reflect the wanted result.

```js
const
    edges = [{ source: "a", target: "a1" }, { source: "a", target: "a2" }, { source: "a1", target: "a1a" }, /* { source: "a1a", target: "b" }, { source: "a2", target: "b" }, { source: "b", target: "c" }, */ { source: "c", target: "c1" }],
    nodes = [{ name: "a", data: { type: "parallelNode", isRoot: true } }, { name: "b", data: { isRoot: true } }, { name: "c", data: { type: "parallelNode", isRoot: true } }, { name: "a1", data: { type: "parallelNode" } }, { name: "a1a", type: "" }, { name: "a2" }, { name: "c1" }],
    parents = Object.fromEntries(edges.map(({ source, target }) => [target, source])),
    tree = function (edges, parents, root) {
        const t = {};
        nodes.forEach(({ name }) => {
            const parent = parents[name];
            Object.assign(t[name] = t[name] || {}, { name });
            t[parent] ??= { name: undefined };
            t[parent].parallel ??= {};
            t[parent].parallel.tasks ??= [];
            t[parent].parallel.tasks.push(t[name]);
        });
        return t[root].parallel.tasks;
    }(edges, parents, undefined);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```